# Firefox layout issues with 32 bit and 64 bit systems Version 12.0

Tags: asp.net, firefox, windows-7

we have a web application built on ASP.Net we usually test the system on all browsers but recently we found that the Firefox V 12.0 on 32 bit OS shows layout properly but on 64 bit OS on Windows 7 shows it cluttered.

Any idea for this sort of issues with the same version of browser acting differently like this?

Comment: Is there any *other* difference in the two systems? Installed fonts, installed add-ons, etc...

Comment: both systems we tested are same fresh installed Windows 7 SP1 latest browser installed from mozilla.org site v 12 only difference is 32 bit and 64 bit. The 64 bit layout issue occurs not only on the 64 bit firefox on windows 7 but on the Mac OS X Lion too which has Firefox 12.0 64 bit.